# Angular 5 component test get debugElement by ID

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, angular-components

I have a component containing 3 select dropdowns with no css classes attached and a unique Id on each.  In my component I want to get the elements as DebugElements so that I can test their states after various events have been triggered.  From the Angular website there is `debugElement.query(By.css('[attribute]'));`.  How can I get my dropdowns By.id

Comment: `By.css('#someId')`?

Comment: Worked thanks, didn't know you could do that

Comment: `element`, `.class`, `#id`, `[attribute]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe

```
By.css('#someId')
```

Comment: From where you are importing 'By'?

Comment: @AnandRaj import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";

Answer (score 2):

**Angular 7 get debugElement by ID**

The debugElement.query iterates all debugElements and returns those found to be true via  a predicate.  This example shows how to do it in one line of code.

```
var test = fixture.debugElement.query((de)=>{return de.nativeElement.id==="someId"});
```